# Background file upload in Blackberry WebWorks

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I'm writing a Blackberry Z10 app for use in onsite events where we take photos or short videos of attendees and the photos are available immediately on a website.  We take the photo, enter a message to be displayed with it and the photo gets uploaded right then.  We initially used blackberry.io.filetransfer.upload but the videos could be up to 30MB so would have a long wait time, so we switched to an XHR transfer where we could have a progress bar so at least the app user would have something to look at.

We've found that sometimes they're in areas with low connectivity, so would like to just copy the file to a folder that is watched by a background process and anything deposited there gets uploaded to the server.  How can we get an app functioning basically as a service, doing file transfers even when minimized?

Comment: There is no problem doing this sort of thing on the BB10 in native/Cascades, even before 10.2 with headless apps, so I am not sure what you are having problems with.  Can you explain the issues you think you will face doing this?  And does this app have to be a WebWorks app?

Comment: I know you can use native libraries in WebWorks, can't you do it with that?